# Unlock cursor through script

Tags: unity, input, mouse

I am using unity's default FPS controller script. My game switches scenes, and when it does I can't move the mouse. I know that this is because of unity's m_mouselook's lock cursor is on. What I don't know how to do is turn that boolean to false through a different script.

Comment: Can you not just call `name_of_mouselock_var = false`?

Comment: no, because it uses a folder of variables or something weird like that,

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Unity 5 just type `Cursor.LockMode = LockMode.Unlocked` or whatever the lock modes unlocked mode is

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with the API, please don't just guess. There is no `LockMode` under `Cursor` as per the Unity API.